# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse .. strange array init?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
      data[config]();
```

Please explain what this does.  (bootstrap collapse)

```
Collapse._jQueryInterface = function _jQueryInterface(config) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data(DATA_KEY);
    var _config = $.extend({}, Default, $this.data(), (typeof config === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(config)) === 'object' && config);

    if (!data && _config.toggle && /show|hide/.test(config)) {
      _config.toggle = false;
   }

    if (!data) {
      data = new Collapse(this, _config);
      $this.data(DATA_KEY, data);
    }

    if (typeof config === 'string') {
      if (data[config] === undefined) {
        throw new Error('No method named "' + config + '"');
      }
      data[config]();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!data) {
  data = new Collapse(this, _config);
  $this.data(DATA_KEY, data);
}
```

So `data` is an instance of Collapse plugin.

`config` is a paremeter of `_jQueryInterface` function.

It means that if you pass to that function `toggle` string - `data[config]` will be `data['toggle']`. And `toggle` is a method of Collapse plugin. Then, if you add `()` to that you can run that method.

Toggle method:

```
Collapse.prototype.toggle = function toggle() {
  if ($(this._element).hasClass(ClassName.SHOW)) {
    this.hide();
  } else {
    this.show();
  }
};
```

To summarize, `data[config]()` runs Collapse plugin method depending on the `config` argument (it might be `show`, `hide`, or `collapse`).

Comment: If you have other similar problems, you can always `console.log` these things in Bootstrap's code, for example you can write `console.log(data)` or `console.log(data[config])` and when you click on your collapsible elements you will see what these things are in the console :).

Comment: And one more thing, brackets in `data[config]` it doesn't mean that data is an array, in this case data is an object and you can access object keys using dot or brackets, so it can be `data.toggle()` or `data['toggle']()`. But you can't write `data.'toggle'()`, that's why they used bracket notation.